# Overheating on Dell Studio XPS 1645

Tags: cpu, overheating, dell-studio-xps-16

So I was wondering if anyone else has come upon this problem, and/or has come up with a solution. When I use my Ubuntu partition, my computer becomes extremely hot, and the fan runs very noisily for a very long time. If I reboot into windows while this is happening, my computer actually begins to cool down while doing the exact same tasks. Thinking this might just be a bug with Ubuntu, I installed fedora on another partition, and the same problem occurs. Is this a problem with the kernel? Cpufreq tells me that my CPU is running at 933 MHz out of a possible 1.6 GHz from my Intel Core i7 CPU Q70. For anyone who wants more information, I have 8 GB of memory, and an ATI Mobility Raedon HD 5730 Graphics Card. I'm open to any ideas anyone might have. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If possible, please consider closing some of your other open questions by [selecting the best answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer) (if they have one). Consider which answers have been useful and need an upvote. We need users to maintain their questions so that the site can be an effective tool for the next person with your problems. For more details on best practices consider reading [the FAQ on asking questions](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an overheating problem with some Intel processors running Linux kernel < 3.2 (power regressions). This issue, I read, has been fixed in 12.04 (Linux
kernel 3.2) So upgrade to 12.04 when it is released in 16
days. Hope this helps

Comment: You are welcome. I know how you feel as I have a similar overheating problem. Power management was given serious attention for 12.04 so I'm sure all these problems have been dealt with. You can even try a live CD/USB of the latest 12.04 build to verify if the problem has been dealt with

Answer (score 0):

Although your computer has some mighty powerful specs for the time of writing, I'd recommend giving Lubuntu a spin (Ubuntu with LXDE). I know LXDE is ideal for old computers, but I've tried running Ubuntu and Lubuntu on an old HP laptop, on Ubuntu with Unity (even in Unity 2D) it would overheat and shut off, whereas with LXDE it would run for much much longer before overheating to the point of shutting off. LXDE may not be as packed with features as Gnome or KDE, but I'd still use Linux with LXDE over windows on any hardware. If that does make a difference, you may then want to give Xubuntu a spin, see if you prefer Xfce or LXDE (LXDE is lighter than Xfce, but you may find that Xfce is light enough and has a few more features). Also you could try formatting your Linux partition with different filesystems.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem...and a BIOS Update fixed my problem..Hope this piece of information helps.